# Send file with Bluetooth in React Native

Tags: react-native, bluetooth

Is it possible to connect and send file with Bluetooth using React Native ?

I try `react-native-ble-plx` mobule, but the scan show only 2/10 devices .. and on the doc, i see `communicating between phones using BLE (Peripheral support)`.

Anyone have already work with this ? Maybe other module ?

Thank you community !

Comment: did you figure it out? Have you found any library supporting device to device data transfer?